# XMing "can't open display" error

Tags: putty, x11forwarding

Attempting to run [XMing](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xming/), the remote host is Ubuntu, going through Putty.  Have spent hours carefully double-checking all settings, reviewing XMing's troubleshooting guide, etc.  Rather than continuing this path, I want to use a tracing tool or `sshd` logging to somehow identify exactly why I'm getting the "can't open display" error.  This occurs when I test by running`xclock` or firefox.

I've turned off firewalls on each computer.

One thing that bothers me: in Putty I'm setting the X display location to `localhost:0`, which they say sets the `DISPLAY` variable on the remote host.  But after logging in through Putty, I do an `echo $DISPLAY` and it shows nothing.  Shouldn't it return `localhost:0`?

What tools or logs or other approach could I use to figure out what's wrong?

Comment: I'm also experiencing this exact same scenario... have you figured this out?

Comment: @David would you mind choosing an answear or are there still problems you face?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to set the display location to `localhost:0.0` instead of `localhost:0`.

[image]

If this wont work, at `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` check for LogLevel variable to be set to `LogLevel INFO`.

Now you could retry your connection and do the following for more log information:
`sudo cat /var/log/* | grep DISPLAY`
or
`sudo cat /var/log/* | grep ssh`
or
`sudo cat /var/log/* | grep sshd`
etc.

Answer (score 8):

I had to put in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` the following:

```
X11UseLocalhost no
```

Otherwise the display variable wouldn't get set. Now it works for me.

Answer (score 2):

If you set `localhost:0` as "X display location" option in Putty, you should also check that Xming is running on display `:0`. Xming and Putty display option must have the same value.

Once connected on the Ubuntu, you should run `export DISPLAY=10.0.0.1:0`, assuming that your client has the address `10.0.0.1` and Xming is running on display `:0`.

Also, if that does not solve the problem, you can try to launch Xming with the option `-ac`. To do so on Windows, either launch it from command line, or by making a shortcut in which you append "-ac" in its "target" property. Be careful though, this will allow anyone to use your X server, so do this on trusted networks only. The `export DISPLAY` command should also be ran on the Ubuntu.

If the option `-ac` solves the problem, I must say I don't know how to configure Xming or whatever that prevents you to have the same result without `-ac`.

Comment: And where would in Xming, such setup be hiding ? Tks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using ArchLinux as my server and I didn't have xauth installed.
I did `pacman -S xorg-xauth` to have xauth installed and then it worker.